# Row Range Filter vs Substring comparator - Hbase

Tags: java, hbase

My Hbase `rowkeys` are set up like this: `timestamp-userid`

I need to scan through all the rows in hbase and return anything with `userid = 38356644322545651`

So we have

```
vid = "38356644322545651";
```

At the moment I'm using a little hack, a substring comparator:

```
Scan s = new Scan();
Filter f = new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new SubstringComparator(vid));
s.setFilter(f);
```

**This works perfectly!**

However, I question the efficiency of checking for the existence of a substring.
Also in the future if there were other `rowkeys` containing the above `rowkey` that could cause problems.

So I found something called a `MultiRowRangeFilter`.

It seems pretty straight-forward. My implementation is as follows:

```
Scan s = new Scan();
List<MultiRowRangeFilter.RowRange> lst = new ArrayList<MultiRowRangeFilter.RowRange>();
lst.add(new MultiRowRangeFilter.RowRange("0-" + vid, true, "z-" + vid, true));
s.setFilter(new MultiRowRangeFilter(lst));
```

This doesn't seem to work at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply to say, `MultiRowRangeFilter` is not suit for your scenario.**
**If worried about the efficiency and correctness, I recommend `RegexStringComparator`** :

```
    int len = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()).length();
    String expr = "^[0-9]{" + len + "}" + String.valueOf(seperator) + vid + "$";

    // just kidding... not rely on flag at all.. use 0
    int flag = Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL;
    RegexStringComparator.EngineType engineType = RegexStringComparator.EngineType.JAVA;

    RowFilter rowFilter = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
            new RegexStringComparator(expr, flag, engineType));
```

If want to try with `MultiRowRangeFilter`, start key should be `0000000000000-vid`, end key should be `9999999999999-vid`, the code like below:

```
    int len = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()).length();
    String startPrefix = getStrOfRepeatedChar(len, '0'),
            endPrefix = getStrOfRepeatedChar(len, '9');

    String startRow = startPrefix + String.valueOf(seperator) + wantedId,
            endRow = endPrefix + String.valueOf(seperator) + wantedId;
    RowRange rowRange = new RowRange(startRow, true, endRow, true);

    List<RowRange> rowRangeList = new ArrayList<>();
    rowRangeList.add(rowRange);

    Filter multiRowRangeFilter = new MultiRowRangeFilter(rowRangeList);
```

**But the result is still incorrect as it will display all results in the table.**

Comment: Excellent. I never heard of RegexComparator. Just to clarify, suppose I wanted any `vid` from a certain `timestamp` range. Could I use the following Row Rane Filter for example: `14476000000-0` -> `z-z`? Since we know `yyyy` is between `0` and `z` in ascii/unicode format

Comment: ```a certain timestamp range```, i assume that there are both startTimestamp and endTimestamp, is that right ? if so, just Row Rane Filter from ```startTimestamp-``` to  ```endTimestamp-```  may do the work, i'm not so sure that's your question :)

Comment: Basically, is it true that `yyyyy` is between `0` and `z` in the context of a `RowRangeFilter`?